# How to setup filters to catch 4FSK deviations

Tags: gnuradio, radio

I'm trying to demodulate a radio signal from Motorol DP4801 (MOTOTRBO) that follows DMR specification.

I'm receiving the signal by using HackRF with the rate sample 1 MHz. The radio uses frequency 406MHz. According to the standard DMR uses 4FSK modulation with the following deviations:

Symbol +3 - +1,944 kHz

Symbol +1 - +0,648 kHz

Symbol -1 - -0,648 kHz

Symbol -3 - -1,944 kHz

The RF carrier bandwidth is 12,5 kHz.

Because after the sampling the radio signal I've lost the original signal (406 MHz) I can't understand how I should set up bandpass filters to catch these deviations. I need it because I'm going to apply non-coherent FSK demodulation but as in the image but for 4 symbols.

[image]

Comment: the 12.5 kHz isn't compatible at all with the frequency deviations you post.

Comment: @MarcusMüller thanks for the comment, why do you think so? Difference between  -3 and +3 deviations is ~4 kHz. As I can see, they fit 12.5 kHz bandwidth.